# how can make throttling per user per api and per resource of the api in wso2 api management 2.6?

Tags: publish-subscribe, wso2-api-manager, wso2, throttling

I am using wso2 API management 2.6. I have 15 API in my store and every API has 5-10 resources (many 'get'-'post'-'delete'-'put'). I have 3 users (consumers) that every one has his own tiers for calling APIs. for example 'user1' can call just  one 'get' resource of 'API1' ,all 'post' resources of API2 and can not call other resources in API1 , API2 and API3. This situation is same for user2 and user3. I don't know how can I make throttling tiers for this store?

I found this [this](https://medium.com/@lahirugmg/resource-level-rate-limiting-for-each-user-with-wso2-api-manager-3a743bffe846) example and change it to my own one like this :

> key Template:
>   $userId:$resourceKey
>
> siddhi query :
>   FROM RequestStream
>   SELECT userId, ( userId == 'userId@carbon.super'  and resourceKey== '/api/1.0.0/resourceKey:GET') AS isEligible ,
>   str:concat('userId@carbon.super' , ':' , '/api/1.0.0/resourceKey:GET') as throttleKey
>
> INSERT INTO EligibilityStream;
>   FROM EligibilityStream[isEligible==true]#throttler:timeBatch(1 min)
>   SELECT throttleKey, (count(userId) >= 1) as isThrottled, expiryTimeStamp group by throttleKey
>   INSERT ALL EVENTS into ResultStream;

I have this siddhi query but it doesn't work!
I don't know this info helps or not but my api request Url is : https://[APIAdress]/api/1.0.0/resourceKey

Comment: You can try writing custom throttling policies based on your use case and apply them to the apis.
Please take a look at the documentation for custom throttling policies.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Adding+New+Throttling+Policies#AddingNewThrottlingPolicies-Addingacustomthrottlingpolicy

Comment: thanks for your reply, I read this before but I can't find any example which includes throttling not just on API, I need a siddhi query sample which throttle the resources (like get , post, put and ..) so I think I should write in some where in the query the name of the resources of API. but I don't know where cause I could't find any sample for this.

Comment: @N.Abdolalizadeh Hi, I would suggest you remove the URL from your question as you have given open access to anyone who sees it, access to your portals since you still have the default credentials in place. Please change/replace with placeholders the username in the siddhi query you have provided in the question as well.

Comment: @N.Abdolalizadeh I'm glad you finally took that down. Also if you visit https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198983/wso2-am I can talk to you about securing your credentials as a first step.